# Potential memory leak when allocating memory space

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, callback, circular-buffer

I got a notification stating "Potential leak of memory pointed to by field '_Myval2'" in a code, that allocates memory and processes data with Boost lockfree spsc_queue. The data is constantly pushed by a callback function (when hardware is active) and I noticed, that indeed the memory usage quickly rises to an unacceptable value. I am having trouble figuring out how to get rid of this memory leak issue. I checked the data transfer and it passes through as expected. Is there a way to delete/deallocate the memory after I push it to the spsc queue?

```
boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<uchar*,boost::lockfree::capacity<10>> q{};

// Callback function
void MyClass::callback(SIGNALTYPE signalInfo)
{
    ...
    PVOID bufferAddress = getBufferAddress();
    processData(bufferAddress);
    break;
    ...
}

// SPSC producer
void MyClass::processData(PVOID bufferAddress)
{
    int size = getBufferSize();
    auto bufferData = std::make_unique<uchar[]>(size); // This code causes a memory leak
    memcpy(bufferData.get(), bufferAddress, size);
    q.push(bufferData.release());
}

// SPSC consumer
std::unique_ptr<uchar[]> MyClass::popData()
{
    std::unique_ptr<uchar[]> output(nullptr);
    if(q.read_available())
    {
        output = std::unique_ptr<uchar[]>(q.front());
        q.pop();
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for making unique pointer in the `processData()`, if you immediately release it? Why does your queue hold naked pointers and not unique pointers? Queue push will fail if queue is full, but you already did release ownership of the pointer, so you end up with a leak.

Comment: `q.push(bufferData.release());` -> `if (q.push(bufferData.get())) { bufferData.release(); }` Otherwise use `spsc_queue<unique_ptr<uchar[]>, ...>` instead.

Comment: @SergeyA [Boost docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html) say that the contained type must be copyable. It's a trend now to avoid `new`/`delete` by using `unique_ptr` and its factories to replace them (IMO a terrible idea, but that's what people are doing...). But I think the "if the queue drops the element there's a leak" is on the money. (Indeed, using `std::make_unique` instead of `new` is a likely performance hazard, because `make_unique` will fill the buffer with 0s but with `new` you can avoid that. Or use `std::make_unique_for_overwrite`.)

Comment: I can see why the compiler might *think* this *could* be a memory leak, but I can't see how it's *actually* a memory leak. Are you sure this is the memory leak?

Comment: @user253751 As SergeyA says, if the queue fails to insert there's a leak.

Comment: @HTNW I am not that familiar with boost spsc. If it wants types to be copyable and doesn't like movable types, it is just outdated and should not be used. There is nothing which prevents single producer lock-free queue to work with movable types. As for the second point, *It's a trend now...* - trends belong in fashion design. In software engineering, we do not follow trends, we follow technical benefits. Creating a `unique_ptr` with immediate release only because there is a *trend* is not technically sound. Use queue which is capable of working with `unique_ptr`, or `new` object manually.

Comment: Indeed it is not possible to use boost spsc with unique_ptr, however the comment by @Remy Lebeau could be accepted as an answer for this particular use case.